# G3D and C++ Syntax, Reference Random

Tags: c++, function, class, random

I'm using G3D and am having trouble accessing the Random class.

I'm new to C++ and don't really know where to look as a reference.

The reference for the random class is here: http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/courses/cs371/f10/G3D/manual/class_g3_d_1_1_random.html

So far I have doubles defined globally:

```
static double xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel;
```

as well as an include for the random library:

```
#include <G3D/Random.h>
```

and then within a function I'm trying to use:

```
 xPos = (double)Random.integer(-10,10);
```

but I get the error:

```
Error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.
```

And I have no idea what to do with it.  I don't see what could be wrong with my syntax and the quick reference guides for C++ I've looked up say that it's valid.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you need an instance of a `Random` object to work on. It looks like you can make one quite simply:

```
Random rnd;
```

And then to use it:

```
xPos = (double)rnd.integer(-10,10);
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb.  Thanks for your help, I've just been staring at that. (I'll accept your answer when time allows.)